Page Breaking Text Box
I'm currently writing a book and need to be able to have a text box that sits to the right of the main text and will split across pages.  I've tried a couple of things, including minipage, wrapfigure, and tcolorbox and I can't seem to get what I want.
\documentclass[openright,twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Required for tables and figures in the multi-column environment - they need to be placed in specific locations with the [H] (e.g. \begin{table}[H])
\usepackage{float}
% Allow wrapping figures
\usepackage{wrapfig}
% Allow floating textboxes that break across pages
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{Bogus}
\author{Ignore Me}
    
\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    \lipsum[1-2]
    
    While the goals of this coding construct are admirable – to avoid the costly lock and all that such entails should we have already met whatever the ultimate purpose of the method happens to be – it fails to understand how the compiler, interpreter, optimiser, scheduler, and, more generally, the execution environment operate.
    \begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,width=0.4\textwidth]
            \textbf{A Quick Note on Volatile}
            
            \lipsum[1][2-12]
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{wrapfigure}
        
    \lipsum[12]
\end{document}

Using this example, my textbox (the "quick note") is properly placed to the right of the text, but it doesn't break across pages because of the wrapfigure.
I've tried simply using the tcolorbox, too, which then lets it break across pages, but then it's not placed correctly (off to the right as though I had an inline image).
\documentclass[openright,twoside,11pt]{book}
{createspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Required for tables and figures in the multi-column environment - they need to be placed in specific locations with the [H] (e.g. \begin{table}[H])
\usepackage{float}
% Allow wrapping figures
\usepackage{wrapfig}
% Allow floating textboxes that break across pages
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{Bogus}
\author{Ignore Me}

\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    \lipsum[1-2]

    While the goals of this coding construct are admirable – to avoid the costly lock and all that such entails should we have already met whatever the ultimate purpose of the method happens to be – it fails to understand how the compiler, interpreter, optimiser, scheduler, and, more generally, the execution environment operate.
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,width=0.4\textwidth]
        \textbf{A Quick Note on Volatile}

        \lipsum[1][2-12]
    \end{tcolorbox}

    \lipsum[12]
\end{document}

What I really want is something like a floating inline textbox in Word, where I have the little box that floats to the right and that will break nicely across pages.  Importantly, the little text box may or may not be larger than the paragraph that it sits next to and would span multiple paragraphs... it would look a little like , but think the "Info" boxes in textbooks.
Here is another attempt, this time using wrapstuff.  In this example, though, "While the goals" is now pulled onto a second page and out of place, but the "A quick note" is page-broken, as would be expected, except that it is all on one page (probably because the wrapstuff container isn't page breaking):
\documentclass[openright,twoside,11pt]{book}
%\usepackage[color=true,bleed=false,size=pocket,paper=white]{createspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Required for tables and figures in the multi-column environment - they need to be placed in specific locations with the [H] (e.g. \begin{table}[H])
\usepackage{float}
% Allow wrapping figures
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{wrapstuff}
% Allow floating textboxes that break across pages
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{Bogus}
\author{Ignore Me}

\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    \lipsum[1-2]

    \begin{wrapstuff}[width=0.4\textwidth]
        \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,width=\textwidth]
            \textbf{A Quick Note on Volatile}
            
            \lipsum[1][2-12]
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{wrapstuff}
    While the goals of this coding construct are admirable – to avoid the costly lock and all that such entails should we have already met whatever the ultimate purpose of the method happens to be – it fails to understand how the compiler, interpreter, optimiser, scheduler, and, more generally, the execution environment operate.

    \lipsum[12]
\end{document}


welcome! I have to say that result looks pretty awful to me. I can't tell what the reading order is and scanning across the image to find the end of the text line is horrible.

I can't compile your example: ! LaTeX Error: File \createspace.sty' not found.` can you correct it?

wrapstuff will do a better job than wrapfig. floatfram might help. however, I'm a bit unclear what you want because the verbal description doesn't match the image i.e. in the picture it isn't to the right of the main text.

Yeah, I couldn't find an image that really showed what I wanted and don't know how to add an image other than through a link in SE :-(  I have changed the sample picture to another example that shows the text box, which I can easily do, but I need the box to break across pages.  I've edited the sample code and provided a second sample that shows the "A Quick Note" properly breaking across two pages.  What I need is that same behaviour of the second example (breaking across pages) mixed with the text box being to the right of text like in the first, if that makes sense.  Thank you for helping!

I tried wrapstuff instead of wrapfigure (just the word swap from example 1 and then move the wrapstuff block on top of the "While the goals" paragraph) and it pulls "While the goals..." onto a second page and although the tcolorbox breaks the text into two boxes, it doesn't have one box on one page and the other on page two :-(

sorry. I didn't mean it would do everything you want, but only that it will probably work better. I don't think there's a latex solution in general. I don't think latex can do this.

At least I learned about wrapstuff -- it seems much more useful for general purposes than wrapfigure.  Thank you for your help!

yes, wrapstuff is much newer so it can use the new paragraph hooks etc. in recent latex. the older packages didn't have the same format to work with.
